# How can we run flyway/migrations script inside Cassandra Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, cassandra, dockerfile, cqlsh

My docker file

```
FROM cassandra:4.0
MAINTAINER me

EXPOSE 9042
```

I want to run something like when cassandra image is fetched and super user is made inside container.

```
create keyspace IF NOT EXISTS XYZ WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };
```

I have also tried out adding a shell script but it never connects to cassandra, my modified docker file is

```
FROM cassandra:4.0
MAINTAINER me

ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN mkdir scripts
COPY alter.cql scripts/
RUN chmod 755 scripts/alter.cql

EXPOSE 9042
CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

My entrypoint looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

export CQLVERSION=${CQLVERSION:-"4.0"}
export CQLSH_HOST=${CQLSH_HOST:-"localhost"}
export CQLSH_PORT=${CQLSH_PORT:-"9042"}

cqlsh=( cqlsh --cqlversion ${CQLVERSION} )

# test connection to cassandra
echo "Checking connection to cassandra..."
for i in {1..30}; do
  if "${cqlsh[@]}" -e "show host;" 2> /dev/null; then
    break
  fi
  echo "Can't establish connection, will retry again in $i seconds"
  sleep $i
done

if [ "$i" = 30 ]; then
  echo >&2 "Failed to connect to cassandra at ${CQLSH_HOST}:${CQLSH_PORT}"
  exit 1
fi

# iterate over the cql files in /scripts folder and execute each one
for file in /scripts/*.cql; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  echo "Executing $file..."
  "${cqlsh[@]}" -f "$file"
done

echo "Done."

exit 0
```

This never connects to my cassandra
Any ideas please help.
Thanks .

Comment: attache output when docker starts

Comment: @AlexOtt  Docker keeps on printing this `Checking connection to cassandra...
Can't establish connection, will retry again in 1 seconds
Can't establish connection, will retry again in 2 seconds
Can't establish connection, will retry again in 3 second`, and terminate out finally

Comment: Do you have it listening on localhost? Maybe try actual container IP instead?

Comment: @AlexOtt It by defaults listen to localhost and i have also mentioned it in shell script, can it be because of execution of shell on the same thread which sort of like a two threads trying to run on same ?? Just thinking out loud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't call the original entrypoint to start Cassandra - you overwrote it with your own code, but it just running the `cqlsh`, without starting Cassandra.

You need to modify your code to start Cassandra using the original entrypoint script ([source](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/master/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh)) that is installed as `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`, and then execute your script, and then wait for termination signal (you can't just exit from your script, because it will terminate the image.